# Vue ChartJS Axis Scale

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

Looking for some help on why my options for the y-axis scale are being ignored. There are no errors in the console, however the y-axis minimum is still generated as the lowest value in the dataset, in this case 24.

The expected result would set the y-axis minimum to zero.

**JS**

```
Vue.component('bar-chart', {
    extends: VueChartJs.Bar,
    props: {
        labels: Array,
        datasets: Array,
        options: Object
    },
    mounted () {
        this.renderChart({
            labels: this.labels,
            datasets: this.datasets,
            options: this.options
        }, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})
    }
})

const home = {
    template: '#home',
    data: function () {
        return {
            labels: ['06/04/21', '06/11/21', '06/18/21', '06/25/21', '07/02/21'],
            datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Count',
                backgroundColor: '#05a7ff',
                data: ['24', '24', '32', '32', '32']
                /*trendlineLinear: {
                    style: "rgb(43 ,66 ,255, 0.3)",
                    lineStyle: "dotted",
                    width: 2
                }*/
            },
            ],
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    position: 'bottom',
                },
                plugins: {
                    datalabels: {},
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            min: 0,
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<template id="home">
    <bar-chart :labels="labels" :datasets="datasets" :options="options"></bar-chart>
</template>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have v2 of the lib installed since if v3 is installed that syntax wont work

Comment: vue-chartjs is v3.5.1 chartjs is v2.7.1

Comment: <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-chartjs/dist/vue-chartjs.min.js"></script> and <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>

Comment: Idk then, seems to work in a normal js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/f90acgzL/1/